# FastAPI is returning AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, fastapi, python-3.9

I am having a very simple FastAPI service, when I try to hit the `/spell_checking` endpoint, I get this error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'.

I am hitting the endpoint using postman, with Post request, and this is the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/spell_checking`, the payload is JSON with value:

```
{"word": "testign"}
```

Here is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, Request
import uvicorn
from typing import Dict

app = FastAPI() 


@app.post('/spell_checking')
def spell_check(word: Dict )  :
    data = {
        'corrected': 'some value'
    }
    return Response(data)

@app.get('/')
def welcome():
    return Response('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I still dont know why a simple service like this would show this error!

Comment: @Chris technically, this is what I wanted to do, yet the error did not specify what's causing it, which I found it weird, that's why I was fed up with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens when you try to create the `Response` object. This object expects a string as input (infact it tries to call `.encode()` on it).

There is no need to explicitly create one, you can just return the data and fastapi will do the rest.

```py
from typing import Dict

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/spell_checking")
def spell_check(word: Dict):
    data = {"corrected": "some value"}
    return data


@app.get("/")
def welcome():
    return "Hello World"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8080, host="0.0.0.0")
```